# Constructive proof of $\forall n, m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\gcd (m,n)=1, $ the cyclic group $C_{nm}\cong C_n\times C_m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Theorem: $\forall n, m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\gcd (m,n)=1, $ the cyclic group $C_{nm}\cong C_n\times C_m$.

This is a corollary of Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The theorem can be recast as saying that doing cyclic permutation on a list of all elements in the product is equivalent to doing so to each of the components. So, there has to be a more direct and intuitive approach. In other words, my goal is to find a constructive proof by explicitly constructing an isomorphism without using CRT (maybe by induction over $n$?), but I don't know where to start since I'm not familiar with permutations. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: The groups $C_4$ and $C_2 \oplus C_2$ are not isomorphic; the latter contains no element of (exactly) 4, for example.

Comment: This is only true if $\gcd(m, n) =1$.

Comment: You may find Sylow and Cauchy Theorem's to be helpful in finding elements of order p which divides one but not the other in creating the isomorphism

Comment: Certainly this has been asked before, it's a classic abstract algebra homework question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** By the extended Euclidian Algorithm, there exists some $a,b$ such that 
$$am+bn=1$$

Show that $f(x)=(ax, bx)$  (or $x^a, x^b$ if you write the cyclic groups multiplicatively) is your isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.What is the order of $(g,h)$ when each of $g$ and $h$ generates the component it's in?

Answer (score 0):

Since cyclic groups are isomorphic to additive groups, set of all proofs of this theorem is "isomorphic", in a sense, to set of all proofs of CRT. Hence, find a constructive proof of CRT, which contains an isomorphism between $\mathbb Z_{nm}$ and $\mathbb Z_{m} \times \mathbb Z_{n}$. Replace every number by its corresponding cyclic permutation to obtain a constructive proof of this theorem.